# Accessing remote RSS feed using Google Feeds API

Tags: javascript, firefox, rss

Basically my question is not about how, its about Why ? :)
Now i will tell what what i know, then tell me what i missing (if any).

In Firefox you can not access remote XML files such as RSS feed using Javascript, because you will get access denied error. Normally to solve it we implement proxy (Internal page to query the content) so we access it locally.

Another solution is to use Goolge Feeds API (or one of the extensions such JQuery extensions built on this API).

My question is very simple? Why does this Google Feed API works and can load the remote XML while with manual script we can not do it ? What i am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Google Feeds API gets the feed contents through a proxy on `www.google.com/uds/something/something`.

This is how it looks like in ASCII architecture.

```
yoursite.com                            |
[1] v    ^ [6]                          |
    v    ^                              |  <-- Client
Google Feeds API JS (on yoursite.com)   |
[2] v    ^ [5]                          |
----v----^----------------------------------------------------------------------
    v    ^                              |
www.google.com/uds/GFeeds?..            |  <-- Server (Proxy)
[3] v    ^ [4]                          |     
    v    ^                              |
www.feed.com/..                         |  <-- Feed URL
```

Comment: Then , why i can not do this using my client side script, why does Firefox gives Access denied if you normally tried to open XML file from remote domain ?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox gives access denied because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which prevents your site from have cross site scripting.